# Is there any API for creating and editing catalog price rules in Magento 2.2.x

Tags: magento2, api, magento2.2, catalog-price-rules, magento2.2.2

I needed to perform this task for a customer where I have to create, edit and delete catalog price rules in his magento site based on some backend functionality in another system he runs internally in his organization. While searching I got to know that although there is an API to handle shopping cart price rules:

> ```
>     GET    /V1/salesRules/:ruleId
>     GET    /V1/salesRules/search
>     POST   /V1/salesRules        
>     PUT    /V1/salesRules/:ruleId
>     DELETE /V1/salesRules/:ruleId
> ```
>
> ([ref](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/list.html))

there is none to handle catalog price rules (as mentioned [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/Catalog-Price-Rule-in-REST-API/idi-p/80896))

Is there possible solution or will it require creation of custom API to handle these rules?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a custom solution for handling catalog price rules via api.

Please find the below link for Reference.

http://mydons.com/magento-2-catalog-price-rule-in-rest-api/